# Failed to load url(angular js)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have given json image url in img src but the img won't loads. when i check the generated url from ng-src the image loads. please help.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="post in posts" href="#/app/post/{{post.ID}}">
    <img ng-src="post.imageurl"/> {{post.title}}
  </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the url like an angular scope variable as follows

```
<img ng-src="{{post.imageurl}}"/>
```

Comment: make it print the url to the page to check that its correct. then double check the assets/img folder you're storing the images in to be sure the path is correct and even try hard coding it in to make sure your path is right